# Using Vaadin with Scala - does it make sense to use framework like Play! or Lift?

Tags: spring, scala, playframework, lift, vaadin

I want to create web application and in meantime learn some cool new framework/technology.
At first I was looking at Spring-Roo and Vaadin, but then I thought it would be more fun (and possibly more productive) to go with something other than pure java.

So far I decided for scala.
But must say that I really like Vaadin for the gui, and if possible I would like to use it.
Probably I could use pure vaadin + scala to build some simple web app, but if it makes sense then I would rather use some existing framework to help me with security, enforce proper mvc or mvp and so on.

Do it make any sense to use Play! or Lift with Vaadin as the frontend? Or maybe something else? Is there any tutorial or documentation for this (I didn't found anything)?

Or maybe I'll be better with just standard Spring (Spring-Roo) and java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lift or play do not add too much to vaadin. Only use case could be to do lightweight page oriented content in play/lift and application oriented parts in vaadin.

Have not seen tutorials on such combinations, but there are plenty on tutorials for using scala with vaadin. Just google for them.

Comment: In this case I think I'll stay with Spring Roo + Vaadin and use Scala for backend if there will be need for that. Thanks for answers guys!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to learn web-technology, I would strongly recommend to use Play, because there you learn the basics: HTML, JavaScript and CSS. Even if you don't want to learn the basics, I would recommend Play, because it has a good productivity and is completely stateless. So it's easy to write a RESTful-application. How ever this is the reason why you cant combine Vaadin with Play. Vaadin and other component-based frameworks are stateful and need an Http-Session.